# .net Profiler to collect long term metrics?

Tags: c#, c++, profiler

We have a Client/Server Application and I'd like to profile both of them to create Metrics like "The average Login Time was xx ms with xxx being max, x being min and a total of xx Logins since yyyy" and so on.

I know the Equatec and ANTS profilers (which I both like a lot). But I think they dont provide the functionality I'd need.

Of course, I could write the necessary functions myself, but I think as ANTS or Equatec can do that on their own pretty good, there must be some way to use that functionality.

What I need:

- Collect as much data about function calls as possible, while still maintaining a reasonable performance
- Scaling would be good like in (de)selecting code paths I do not want to monitor
- Saving all collected Data in a Database, either a local one or a remote SQL DB
- If the tool could create graphs like ANTS on its own, that would be cool, but raw Data would suffice
- Code is written in C# 3.5 (Server and Client<->Server communications) and C++ (Client GUI). It would be good to monitor the C++ code as well (C# is embedded as COM Objects), but for the time being, monitoring C# would be enough

This does not have to come for free, but having a trial for testing is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profilers are more code/function centric and have a large performance impact. Plus it will be impossible to roll out the profiler with your code to your users.
I think you should look at using a logging framework like log4net for your code and then configure the logging to save the results into a database which you can use to analyse the performance figures.

Comment: How much quantitively is "a large performance impact"?  How much can the OP stand?

Comment: Application is not time critical, up to 200 ms would be feasible, I guess.  We already use log4net, so I decided to just implement my own logs to calculate metrics. Actual problem's solved now, but of course im still interested in hearing your ideas :)

Comment: Have a look at the wikipedia entries for profiling and logging. It will become clear that this is a task for logging, not profiling. Futhermore profilers can not become part of a distribution due to license restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options that I could think of right now:

1. Write your own code specifically timing the functions you want to profile (obvious easiest option).
2. Use performance counters ([System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).
3. Roll your own profiler using the [.NET Profiling API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301725.aspx)
4. Use the low level built in OS profiler called [Xperf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/cc825801.aspx) from the performance toolkit.

Edit:
How could I forget this little gem!

[MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) can be wrapped around your code like this:

```
var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current; // it's ok if this is null
using (profiler.Step("Doing complex stuff")){
    using (profiler.Step("Step A"))
    { // something more interesting here
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    using (profiler.Step("Step B"))
    { // and here
        Thread.Sleep(250);
    }
}
```